# Capture video (source webcam) at a specific frame rate in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to capture a video at 15 fps for 45 seconds and store it in a file using Matlab. The source of the video is my laptops webcam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with the documentation of the imaqtool.

then try something like this... (I assume you have imaq toolbox)

```
 vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'RGB24_640x480'); % or any other mode needed
 src = getselectedsource(vid);
 src.FrameRate = '15.0000';
 vid.FramesPerTrigger = 15*45;
 start(vid);
```

etc...

Comment: Yeah! I started with the documentation. Dd work but my problem isn't completely solved. Thanks a lot though!